# MailboxInfoStale when requesting mail folders via Outlook REST API

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi

In our platform, we sync customers' emails via Outlook REST API. However, for some users, we see the next response from the API on an attempt to get her mail folders:

```
{u'error': {u'code': u'MailboxInfoStale',
  u'message': u"Target resource '00034001-82e9-53de-0000-000000000000' hosted on database '9a26be97-b303-4cea-991b-dae4bdaed840' is currently on backend 'Unknown'"}}
```

Request headers:

```
{u'Accept': u'application/json',
 u'Authorization': u'Bearer ...',
 u'Content-Type': u'application/json',
 u'User-Agent': u'Nimble',
 u'X-AnchorMailbox': u'...@...'}
```

The request URL is `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders`.
While googling, I've stumbled upon this post: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/error-improvement-for-invalid-x-anchormailbox-in-rest-api-calls/, but it seems nothing to do with the error we observe.

As an additional clue that might help: attempts to request message listing in a folder (let's say from the "Archive") for one of these accounts will ALWAYS result in a 503 response from Outlook REST API (event if we request a single message without applying `$filter` or `$orderby` parameters).

Comment: any update on this? im experiencing a similar issue

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that was an issue on the MS side. If one of your customers (a user on behalf of whom you make API requests) has a premium support plan on their O365 account - you may want to open a support ticket with Microsoft. In our case, these errors eventually went away (that is, I suspect they had some sort of migration causing these errors).